# Unique column definition in SQL

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I've looked at a few SQL posts already but i'm unsure of their answers.. eg: [SQL Unique Key Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197473/sql-unique-key-syntax)

I want a Cities table... I want to define my country table whereby the Name column is unique... Using this as the base, how do I define a Unique column?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cities]
(
    [CityID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NCHAR(100) NULL
)
```

Comment: I don't know any country where the City name is unique (or forced to be unique).  You may want to question this requirement.

Comment: Also: please **don't use** `NCHAR(100)` - this will cause you to have **fixed-width**, always 100 characters = 200 bytes long entries - even if you store only 3 or 4 characters.... `(N)CHAR(n)` is great for short codes - like ISO country or currency codes - for anything beyond 5 characters, you should use `(N)VARCHAR(n)` instead!

Comment: @Raj More - I have a list of cities going to be added to my table... I don't want multiples added (If there is bad data im taking it from)... That's all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `unique` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cities]
(
    [CityID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NCHAR(100) NULL UNIQUE
);
```

There are alternative methods.  You can add also add a `unique` index:

```
create unique index cities_name on dbo.Cities(Name);
```

Or do it with a `unique` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cities]
(
    [CityID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NCHAR(100) NULL,
    constraint unique_name unique(Name)
);
```

Comment: Do you have a preference? P.S your original suggestion is great. ta.

Comment: I prefer the first, just adding the `unique` constraint if I'm creating the table.  In practice, I might think of this later and add the index.

Comment: I avoid the first approach (UNIQUE inline field). If you need composed unique keys, you cannot use it. Also I think is always better to name your constraints. That's why I take the 2nd or 3rd approach.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 . . . Isn't it great to have different views on the same subject?

Comment: I think i'm going to be sick... hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constraint on the table to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD CONSTRAINT
<constraintname> UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    <columnname>
)
```